# Estructuración dinámica de un CZML con base de datos

Tags: php, javascript

Estoy realizando un proyecto en `CesiumJS` el cual consiste en visualizar datos de buques que pasan por un lugar determinado, pero esta data la tengo en mi base de datos y se desea crear la estructura del `CZML` de forma dinamica con los datos proporcionados en las tablas, actualmente lo e intentado con un `while` pero no me arroja los resultados deseados ya que en el `epoch` se arroja el mismo tiempo por lo que la animación no va a aparecer ya que no transcurre ni un segundo de la misma.

```
var czml = [{
    "id": "document",
    "name":"Vessels Position",
    "version": "1.0",
    "clock": {
        "interval": "2018-09-01T00:00:00Z/2018-09-29T11:14:00Z",
        "currentTime": "2018-09-01T00:00:00Z",
        "multiplier": 400
    }
},


{
"id" : "1",
"name": "BW RADON",
"description": "Vessel Name: BW RADON <br> Flag: United Kingdom <br>Last Port: TUMACO <br> Previous Port: MEJILLONES <br>Destination: BALBOA <br> IMO: 9829679 <br> Callsign: MCWX7 <br> Length: 146.5 <br> Width: 24 <br> Draught: 61 <br> DWT: 19900 <br> Gross Tonnage: 11900 <br> Ship Type: Tanker",
"availability" :"2018-09-12T18:26:41Z/2018-09-12T18:26:41Z",
"position" : {
    "epoch":"2018-09-12T18:26:41Z",
    "cartographicDegrees" : [ 0 , -79.40773 , 8.723151  , 344]
},
"path" : {
    "material" : {
        "polylineArrow" : {
            "color" : {
                "rgba" : [255, 0, 0, 255]
            }
        }
    },
    "width" : 8,
    "leadTime" : 10,
    "trailTime" : 1000,
    "resolution" : 5
},
"billboard" : {
            "image" : "chemical_tanker_icon.png",
            "scale" : 0.5,
    "eyeOffset": {
        "cartesian": [ 0.0, 0.0, -10.0 ]
    }
} 
},...
```

Deseada:

```
var czml = [{
"id": "document",
"name":"Vessels Position",
"version": "1.0",
"clock": {
    "interval": "2018-09-01T00:00:00Z/2018-09-29T11:14:00Z",
    "currentTime": "2018-09-01T00:00:00Z",
    "multiplier": 400
}
},

{
"id" : "sakizaya",
"name" : "Sakizaya Integrity",
"description": "Vessel Name: Sakizaya Integrity <br> Flag: Panama <br> Last 
 Port: Patillos <br> Previous Port: Huasco <br> Destination: US MSY <br> 
  Call Sign: 3FQZ6  <br> IMO: 9780146 <br> DWT: 81010 <br> Draught: 117  
 <br> Width: 32 <br> Length: 229 <br> Gross Tonnage: 43291 <br> Ship Type: 
 Cargo",
"availability": "2018-09-01T00:00:00Z/2018-09-03T14:23:00Z",

  "position" : {
    "epoch":"2018-09-01T00:00:00Z",
    "cartographicDegrees" : [
    0       ,-79.47047  ,8.860931,  0       ,
    850     ,-79.47061  ,8.860559,  209     ,
    1700    ,-79.47086  ,8.86028    ,0       ,
    2550    ,-79.47109  ,8.860102,  0   ,
    3400    ,-79.47195  ,8.859798,  0   ,
    4250    ,-79.4726   ,8.859903,  0   ,
    5100    ,-79.47283  ,8.859883,  0   ,
    5950    ,-79.47285  ,8.859905,  0   ,
    ...
```

Se busca que se cree la estructura de una forma que donde dice `cartographicDegrees` se forme un array con los datos de localización del CZML.

Este es mi código actualmente que me genera dinamicamente con los datos de la base de datos:

```
<?php
require 'conexion.php';
$query = "SELECT * from vessel_complete";
$result = pg_query($dbconn, $query);
$image = "";
while($row = pg_fetch_row($result)){
?>
{
"id" : "<?php echo $row[0]; ?>",
"name": "<?php echo $row[20]; ?>",
"description": "Vessel Name: <?php echo $row[20]; ?> <br> Flag: <?php echo 
$row[21]; ?> <br>Last Port: <?php echo $row[22]; ?> <br> Previous Port:  
<?php echo $row[23]; ?> <br>Destination: <?php echo $row[24]; ?> <br> IMO: 
<?php echo $row[18]; ?> <br> Callsign: <?php echo $row[19]; ?> <br> Length:  
<?php echo $row[13]; ?> <br> Width: <?php echo $row[14]; ?> <br> Draught:  
<?php echo $row[15]; ?> <br> DWT: <?php echo $row[16]; ?> <br> GrossTonnage: 
<?php echo $row[17]; ?> <br> Ship Type: <?php echo $row[12]; ?>",
"availability" :"<?php echo rtrim($row[9])?>T<?php echo rtrim($row[10])
?>Z/<?php echo rtrim($row[9])?>T<?php echo rtrim($row[10])?>Z",
"position" : {
    "epoch":"<?php echo rtrim($row[9])?>T<?php echo rtrim($row[10])?>Z",
    "cartographicDegrees" : [ 0 , <?php echo $row[5]; ?>    , <?php echo 
$row[6]; ?> , <?php echo $row[7]; ?>]
},
"path" : {
    "material" : {
        "polylineArrow" : {
            "color" : {
                "rgba" : [255, 0, 0, 255]
            }
        }
    },
    "width" : 8,
    "leadTime" : 10,
    "trailTime" : 1000,
    "resolution" : 5
},
"billboard" : {
    <?php 
    if($row[11] == "Container Ship"){
        $image = '"container_icon.png"';
    } else if($row[11] == "Bulk Carrier"){
        $image = '"bulk_carrier_icon.png"';
    } else if($row[11] == "Chemical Tanker"){
        $image = '"chemical_tanker_icon.png"';
    } else if($row[11] == "Crude Oil Tanker"){
        $image = '"crude_oil_icon.png"';
    } else if($row[11] == "General Cargo"){
        $image = '"general_cargo_icon.png"';
    } else if($row[11] == "LNG Tanker"){
        $image = '"lng_tanker_icon.png"';
    } else if($row[11] == "LPG Tanker"){
        $image = '"lpg_tanker_icon.png"';
    } else if($row[11] == "Vehicles Carrier"){
        $image = '"vehicles carrier.png"';
    }else if($row[11] == "Oil/Chemical Tanker"){
        $image = '"oil_and_chemical_icon.png"';
    }
    ?>
    "image" : <?php echo $image ?>,
    <?php
    if($row[14] <= 44 ){ //neo panamax
        $scale = 0.5;
    }else{
        $scale = 0.7;
    }
    ?>
    "scale" : <?php echo $scale ?>,
    "eyeOffset": {
        "cartesian": [ 0.0, 0.0, -10.0 ]
    }
    } 
    },
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Adjunto una imagen representativa de lo que se quiere lograr, la misma fue tomada del proyecto pero con información estática[image: Imagen del proyecto estatico].

Espero puedan resolver mis dudas, gracias de antemano.